# Code Prettifying?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

C# code posted to stack overflow gets prettified 
[Find Dangles of road shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223333/find-dangles-of-road-shapefile)

... but not in GIS Stack Exchange.

[Changing feature class and field aliases in bulk using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255/arcgis-change-feature-class-and-field-aliases-in-bulk)

Is that something we could get from them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I enabled code styling on GIS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that prettifying is going to enabled soon.